# How to use intro.js on d3.js elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, intro.js

I'm using d3.js to generate a sankey graph and I'm using intro.js for a guided tour of the page. Intro.js works on all of my pages except the d3 graphs. For instance, I also use intro.js to take a tour of other elements that are also dynamically generated by the js library DataTables and it works perfectly.

My code for the DataTables tour:

```
document.getElementById('help').onclick = function (){
  var intro = introJs();
    intro.setOptions({
      steps: [
        { 
          intro: "These are the results of your search."
        },
        {
          element: "[name=DataTables_Table_0_length]",
          intro: "Select how many results to view.",
          position: "right"
        },
        {
          element: "[type=search][aria-controls=DataTables_Table_0]",
          intro: 'Here you can search the table.',
          position: 'left'
        },
        {
          element: "[class=ColVis]",
          intro: "To show or hide columns, use this.",
          position: "left"
        },
        {
          element: "[class=DTTT_container]",
          intro: "Use these buttons to download, print or copy the data in the     table.",
          position: "left"
        },
        {
          intro: "Select an NPI to view its homepage and we'll continue from there."
        }
      ],
      'showBullets': true,
      'skipLabel': 'Let me drive',
      'doneLabel': "Try it out"
    });

intro.start();
};
```

All of these elements are dynamically generated but are recognized by intro.js when called.

However, when I try the same thing with the d3 elements, intro.js can't find them.

```
document.getElementById('help').onclick = function (){
  var intro = introJs();
    intro.setOptions({
      steps: [
        { 
          intro: "These are the results of your search."
        },
        {
          element: "[class=legend-items]",
          intro: "This is the legend.",
          position: "right"
        }
      ],
      'showBullets': true,
      'skipLabel': 'Let me drive',
      'doneLabel': "Try it out"
    });

    intro.start();
};
```

Here's a screenshot of my d3 graph:
[image]

Has anyone faced this problem and can shed some light for me?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an open issue on the intro.js repo: https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/66

Comment: I went down that rabbit hole without any success.

Finally had luck with "bootstrap tour", though it's not perfect. http://bootstraptour.com/
You can even get mathjax to render inside the tour elements.